# Question on Radon measure's Lebesgue decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Hi all seeing as how people were so nice to me and my experience was a success I though perhaps it was safe to try and ask this as well on Radon measures (also same class)

I am given a $ \sigma-finite $ Radon measure $ \mu $  on X and $ \nu \in M(X)$ a measure such that I am given the Lebesgue decomposition of $ \nu $ with respect to $ \mu $
i.e. $ \nu = \nu_1 + \nu_2 $. I am asked to prove here that $ \nu_1 $ and $ \nu_2 $ are also Radon measures. I am asked to use a previous exercise which I could actually do and it was alright for me, it was as follows (found it also on the site):
Suppose that μ is a Radon measure on X. If ϕ∈L1(μ) and ϕ≥0, then $ \nu(E)= \int_{E}\phi d\mu $ is a Radon measure.
Where I am stuck: I can understand this intuitively but for some reason can't do it. What I do know from Radon-Nikodym is that $ \nu_1 $ is mutually singular with $ \mu $ and also that $ \nu_2 << \mu $ I cannot move further. I think the hypotheses that we are dealing with $ \sigma-finite $ measure spaces is because Radon-Nikodym relies on this assumption but maybe it has a different meaning

Progress: The M(X) is the space of all complex Radon measures. I can get by with showing that $ \nu_2 $ is Radon by the other exercise I told about now how do I show $ \nu_1 $ is Radon? Help please?

Comment: I figured out something important: that $ \nu_2 $ is basically integrating with respect to a (positive) function f on the whole space X but to invoke the previous exercise mentioned I ought to show that the function is not only positive but integrable that is $ \nu_2(X) $ should be a finite integral on X but I don't think Radon-Nikodym guarantees this. Also $ \nu_1 << \mu $ which I know $ \mu $ is Radon maybe this can be helpful?

Comment: What is your definition of $M(X)$? Does that not mean that $\nu$ (and hence also $\nu_2$) is finite? Further hint: Once you know that $\nu_2$ is finite, you have $\nu_1 = \nu -\nu_2$, so that $\nu_1$ is also Radon.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Appreciate your comment thanks now I can tackle $ \nu_2 $ being Radon but I understand not your explanation that $ \nu_1 = \nu - \nu_2 $ is also Radon? Could you further explain this to me? Thank you

Comment: @PhoemueX: BTW I checked with my teacher the meaning of the M(X) is complex Radon measures on X which is a Borel measure whose real and imaginary parts are signed Radon measures with a signed Radon measure being a Borel measure whose positive and negative parts are Radon measures

Comment: @PhoemueX Ok got it now Radon measures are a vector space. Thanks mate